# Unable to perform segue

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4, uistoryboard

I have to navigate from one screen to another on the click of the tableview cell plus i want the data on my cell to be transferred on the respective labels on my second view.i have connected the two view using a segue. how do i go about further ?thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have **VC1**, which has a `UITableView`, and **VC2**. When a VC1 `UITableViewCell` is tapped, VC2 is shown with info from the cell. Schematically, in VC1 you implement:

```
#pragma mark - Table view delegate for VC1
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    dataForVC2 = [vc1DataSource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:segueFromVC1ToVC2 sender:self];
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:segueFromVC1ToVC2]) {
        vc2 = (VC2ViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];
        vc2.delegate = (id)self;
        vc2.whatIWantFromVC1 = dataForVC2;
    }
}

#pragma mark - VC2 delegate
- (void)VC2ControllerDidFinish:(VC2ViewController *)controller
{
    dataBackFromVC2 = controller.propertyForVC1;
}
```

This is how you manage the segue. You also need to implement a delegate protocol for VC2, which is described very well in the WWDC 2011 Apple video, "Introduction to Storyboarding".

It is a lot of conceptual information to absorb but once you have understood the `UITableView datasource` & `delegate`, *protocols*, `UINavigationController`, and *segues* then sophisticated UIs become straightforward to implement. A happy 2 days of hitting the Apple docs and the WWDC videos will lift the veil!

Answer (score 1):

You really need to learn objective-C before jumping into the project development.
here's a link to Apple's book:
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/objc.pdf

Comment: is the question wrong??? i jus needed to know how do u do it i have tried other-ways too if sum one can answer to this thanks..